# Data validation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-webpages

I'm using Entity Framework with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor 3). I have my validation code ready, i'm using Entity Frameworks own validation process. But there is a problem, for example there is a decimal field named **Amount** in my model and database. I use something like this:

```
Item.Amount = decimal.Parse(Request.Form["ItemAmount"]);
```

Here is the problem, if input is non numeric, i get an error (obviously). I can fix it easily by checking if input is numeric but if i do that, there are too many validation checks that way. I mean, i check if it's numeric first in code, then Entity Framework checks the value again so i'm using two different validation process, it seems bad to me.

Ofcourse there is a client side too, maybe i can use numeric only textboxes, still i'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Here is the full code, it's probably horrible, i'm pretty new to Entity Framework (like 3-4 days):

```
if (IsPost)
{
    try
    {
        Worker curWorker = new Worker();
        try
        {
            curWorker = m.Workers.Find(decimal.Parse(Request.Form["WorkerId"]));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errors += "Lütfen bir personel seçin. <br />";
        }

        overhour.Worker = curWorker;
        overhour.PhaseId = curPhase.PhaseId;

        try
        {
            overhour.OverhourAmount = decimal.Parse(Request.Form["OverhourAmount"]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errors += "Süre (Saat) alanı sayısal olmalıdır. <br />";
        }

        overhour.OverhourDate = DateTime.Today;

        curWorker.Overhours.Add(overhour);

        Accounting accounting = new Accounting();
        accounting.AccountingMethod = 0;
        accounting.AccountingNote = curWorker.WorkerFullName + " adlı personelin, " + overhour.OverhourAmount + " saat süreli, " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " tarihli mesai kaydı.";
        accounting.AccountingType = 3; // Maaş
        accounting.AccountingBorc = 0;
        accounting.AccountingAlacak = curWorker.WorkerOverWorkSalary * overhour.OverhourAmount;

        accounting.Phases = curPhase;

        curWorker.Accountings.Add(accounting);

        if (errors != "")
        {
            throw new WrongValueException(errors);
        }

        m.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect(Page.ParentPage);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        errors = kStatic.getValidationErrors(ex.EntityValidationErrors, "<br />");
    }
    catch (WrongValueException ex)
    {
        errors = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errors = "Bilinmeyen hata, teknik detaylar: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use model binding instead - why query `Request.Form` when you can have your `Post` action accept a complex data type, and let MVC perform the binding and validation.  Then you can just check `Model.IsValid`

Comment: @BrendanGreen I'm not using MVC actually, i tried it, worst problem was that binding for me, i don't know why.

Comment: Please show the entire Post action.

Comment: You must make the input field numeric: `<input type="number" />`. But I really suggest learning model binding, it was hard for me to get at first but now that I understand it it's a lot easier to create forms and submit them.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Is it possible to use binding in ASP.Net Web Pages? I can't find any source on it.

Comment: I don't know this technology, can't help you here. But if you can't find resources maybe you can't

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding

Comment: @BrendanGreen It seems model binding is not available for ASP.Net Web Pages. I guess Microsoft thinks it's too advanced for Web Pages. It's weird because Web Pages is very similar to PHP and PHP is arguably the biggest web development enviroment out there, people do many advanced stuff with it.

Comment: Did you actually read the link posted?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes, i did. Looks like it's for Web Forms, i'm not using Web Forms. I also checked it online because i thought maybe i don't understand how to use it with Web Pages but like i said, i think it's not supported in Web Pages.

Comment: @user5273382 ah sorry - missed that bit.  Looks like you're out of luck with the model binding, unless you decide to move to a different model

Comment: @BrendanGreen Thanks, i will use MVC soon but i'm learning Entity Framework and Razor in Web Pages too so it won't be waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is make an extension method, for example like these two.

```
    public static decimal AsDecimal(this string value)
{
    decimal result;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, out result) ? result : 0;
}

public static decimal? AsNullableDecimal(this string value)
{

    decimal result;
    bool IsValid = decimal.TryParse(value, out result);

    if (IsValid)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then simply check the value of decimal like this.

```
decimal? value = Request.Form["WorkerId"].ToString().AsDecimal()

if (value.HasValue) //AsDecimal is overloaded you can make it return 0 if you wish
 //dome something
else
//do something.
```

I think this should point you in right direction. Also on  that note CLIENT validation is bad users can always change this using tools like developer tools. Don't rely on client validation.